# Cannot install plugin for IBM Container on Cloud Foundry on mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, cloud-foundry

The following command :
cf install-plugin https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-containers-mac
directly coming from Bluemix documentation does not seem to work. I'm getting the following error msg:

...
Attempting to download binary file from internet address...
FAILED
Download attempt failed: Error downloading file from https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-containers-mac
Unable to install, plugin is not available from the given url.*

Answer (score 2):

in fact I think I found the answer to my question, posting it just in case it helps somebody else. I did the following:
1. add a plug-in repo to the list of repo:
*cf add-plugin-repo IBM-plugins http://plugins.ng.bluemix.net*
2. install IBM-Containers plugin from that repo:
*cf install-plugin IBM-Containers -r IBM-plugins*

Comment: the following works as well :cf install-plugin http://public.dhe.ibm.com/cloud/bluemix/cli/cf-plugins/ibm-containers-mac>

Comment: The problem is that when trying to use cf ic <command> it does not work, it says:  FAILED
Cloud Foundry CLI version 6.11.2 or later is required for the IBM Containers plug-in.Upgrade your Cloud Foundry CLI installation to continue.<br>and I've got cf 6.13.0 installed...